# How to "remember" last visited tabFragment and open it onResume?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, sharedpreferences, android-tablayout

I have app using TabLayout and ViewPager.

I got it working smooth and nicely, but the thing what bothers me, is that when i open activity from tabs, I'd like to have same tab opened on next time i return back to that activity.

Which is the best practise to produce what I need, using SharedPreferences?

This is as far I got it:

```
private SharedPreferences prefs;
private String LAST_TAB = "last_tab";

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    prefs = this.getSharedPreferences("com.myapp", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    int selTab = prefs.getInt(LAST_TAB, 0);
    /* TODO: How do I procrammatically select tab? */

}

private void setTab() {
    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.myTabs);

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            int selTab = tab.getPosition();

            viewPager.setCurrentItem(selTab);
            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
            editor.putInt(LAST_TAB, selTab);
            editor.apply();
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }    

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }    
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your data is persistent, then you may use SharedPreferences, else if you only need to access data while app is running, you can store it in some variable, Something like :

```
selectedTabIndex // set this value from sharedpreference
TabLayout.Tab selectedTab = tabLayout.getTabAt(selectedTabIndex);
selectedTab.select();
```

Comment: Great. I used this and it worked as expected. Thanks